# Error during evaluation of expression in optim()

Tags: r, optimization, metaprogramming

I'm implementing a function in R for finding the parameters that minimize the quadratic error for an arbitrary pdf function (e.g., pnorm, punif, pbinom, etc.). The design is such that the user provides probabilities, empirical quantiles, a function name (`densit`), and a list of parameter names (`params`) from the `densit` function (e.g., `mean` and `sd` in `pnorm`). For instances, being for `q1`, `q2`, and `q3` equal to -1.644854, 0, and 1.644854, and `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` equal to 0.05, 0.5, 0.95, the function should recover `mean` and `sd` as approximately 0 and 1 respectively.

The goal is to feed such expression to `optim`, so that the latter takes a function (called internally `quadraticFun`) that should evaluate an expression during optimization; however, I can't make `optim` work on such expression for estimation. The function is this:

```
fun  <- function(p1 = 0.05, p2 = 0.50, p3 = 0.95, q1, q2, q3, output = "complete", densit, params) {
    densit <- substitute(densit)
    params <- sapply(params, as.name)
    densiCall1 <- as.call(c(as.list(densit), as.list(q1), params))
    densiCall2 <- as.call(c(as.list(densit), as.list(q2), params))
    densiCall3 <- as.call(c(as.list(densit), as.list(q3), params))
    quadratEq <- substitute((densiCall1 - p1)^2 +
                            (densiCall2 - p2)^2 +
                            (densiCall3 - p3)^2)
    quadraticFun <- function(params) {
        eval(quadratEq)
    }    
    initVals <- rep(1, times = length(params))
    res <- optim(initVals, quadraticFun) # ERROR SOMEWHERE AROUND HERE...
    # if output is set to "complete", return the whole res object, otherwise, return just the parameters 
    if (output == "parameters") {
        return(res$par)
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Debugging with the next example indicates that the error shows up during the call `optim(initVals, quadraticFun)`, specifically during evaluation of `quadraticFun` with the following message:

```
> findParams(q1 = -1.644854, q2 = 0, q3 = 1.644854, densit = pnorm, params = list("mean", "sd"))
Error in pnorm(-1.644854, mean, sd) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

It seems that the expression resulting is taken literally by the interpreter, i.e., `mean` and `as` as symbols to evaluate instead of arguments in the function to optimize.

Thanks in advance for any hint that helps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `quadraticFun` was not working, because is did not properly hand over the `params` parameter to `densiCall1` function.

I changed the code a bit so that there is only one call which needs to be evaluated, which is easier to handle. Now `densit` is a character string, I am sure this you could be changed.
Here is a function I came up with:

```
findParams <- function(q = c( -1.644854, 0, 1.644854), 
        p = c(0.05,  0.50, 0.95), output = "complete", densit="pnorm",
        params = c("mean", "sd")) {
    l <- length(params)
    cl <- vector("list", 2  + length(params))
    cl[[1]] <- as.name(densit)
    cl[[2]] <- q
    names(cl) <- c(NA, "q", params)
    mode(cl) <- "call"
    quadraticFun <- function(x) {
        cl[3:(l+2)] <- x
        res <- eval(cl)
        sum((res - p)^2)
    }    
    initVals <- rep(1, times = l)
    res <- optim(initVals, quadraticFun)
    if (output == "parameters") {
        return(res$par)
    }
    return(res)
}
```

And it seems to work:

```
findParams()
$par
[1] 0.0001065349 1.0001052494

$value
[1] 2.682477e-09

$counts
function gradient
      67       NA

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to a better way to construct calls and the improvements in implementation of vectorized operations. Your answer solved the problem and was insightful.